# (ControlsFX) How to rename SpreadsheetView column header?

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

i'm a JavaFX newbie and interested to build a spreadsheet application using SpreadsheetView control.

The SpreadsheetView default column header are alphabetical character(A,B,C,...). At this time, i need to rename the column header but cant find the method to do it. Can you guys help me show the way to rename the column header?
Thx guys

Comment: I don't use ControlsFX much, and haven't used `SpreadsheetView`, but don't you just do `spreadsheetView.getGrid().getColumnHeaders().setAll(...);`?

Comment: Wow it worked. Thx James_D!!

Comment: All I did was read the documentation for 30 seconds...

Comment: Hehe .. Seems its just me who lazy to read